# Booting is messed up when tried to clone my main HDD to SSD

Tags: boot, bootloader, disk-management

Im trying to upgrade an old Dell pc and clone the old HDD drive with an SSD

I have connected the new SSD to the connections of the optical drive and used the "MiniTool partition" app to make a clone of the main drive
Althought the process finished "correct" I wasn't able to boot from SSD

Messing with the active partitions etc. I have now ended to not be able to boot the pc if **both** drives are not connected.
When I have only my old HDD connected I have a BIOS message that OS is not present and when there is only the SSD connected I have a blue-screen during boot with a similar message.

As it seems part of the booting is made from HDD and part from SSD and I am really confused how can I restore booting from my old HDD in order to start over (I can't make the SSD the main drive)
My old drive is C: and my SSD is the H: drive

Can you please advise from the disk management screenshot what I've done?
I also pasted the results from CMD>Set command which shows that the C: is actual the booting disk
I would appreciate any advise.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFAcs.jpg)

SystemDrive=C:

SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS

TEMP=C:\Users\tasso\AppData\Local\Temp

TMP=C:\Users\tasso\AppData\Local\Temp

USERDOMAIN=TASSOSD

USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=TASSOSD

USERNAME=tasso

USERPROFILE=C:\Users\tasso

windir=C:\WINDOWS

In CMD> Diskpart >list disk command I have the below which is strange because except the disks 0 and 1, I can see additional disks 2-5 that I don't remember to be there

DISKPART> list disk

Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt

---

Disk 0    Online          223 GB   317 MB

Disk 1    Online          232 GB  1024 KB

Disk 2    No Media           0 B      0 B

Disk 3    No Media           0 B      0 B

Disk 4    No Media           0 B      0 B

Disk 5    No Media           0 B      0 B

DISKPART>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have not managed in any way to make the second (new) drive to work individually.
The solution however to make the first (old) drive to work normally was very simple

I have just made inactive the active partition in 2nd Drive and made active the first partition in 1st Drive as per the below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKoNm.jpg)

That at least sets free the 2nd drive again to try mirroring it again

I hope it helps someone else who will end in the same issue

Cheers